# How to scroll back from bottom to top after adding components to panel which is in jscrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

i have a jscrollpane and i have added panel to it and then inside panel i am adding jlabel and textarea dynamically .
After adding components to the panel dynamically the vertical scroll goes to bottom.
What i want  is bringing verticall scroll to the top . That's my problem how can i solve this any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated .

Here is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class MyGui1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    /**
     * 
     */

    protected JPanel panel;
    protected JTextArea textarea;
    static JFrame frame;
    JLabel Jlabel = null;

    public MyGui1() {
        // to lay out the container's components in a rectangular grid
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        JButton jbutton = new JButton("button");
        jbutton.setActionCommand("button");
        jbutton.addActionListener(this);
        add(jbutton, c);

        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        setBackground(Color.cyan);
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(panel);

        jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        add(jsp, c);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        if ("button".equals(evt.getActionCommand())) {
            execute();
        }
    }

    synchronized public void execute() {

        // to remove all the content of panel
        panel.removeAll();
        // to refresh the window
        repaint();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            Jlabel = new JLabel("Labe1l" + i);
            Jlabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
            panel.add(Jlabel);

            textarea = new JTextArea(3, 3);
            textarea.setText("sample text ");
            textarea.append("\n");
            textarea.setEditable(false);
            // in order to wrap up the data in text area
            textarea.setLineWrap(true);
            panel.add(textarea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        frame.revalidate();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        frame = new JFrame("DesktopSearchEngine");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // adding window listener for exit operation
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                JFrame frame = (JFrame) e.getSource();

                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,
                        "Are you sure you want to exit the application?",
                        "Exit Application", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                } else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                }
            }
        });
        // Add contents to the window GUI part and to perform all operations
        frame.add(new MyGui1());

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        // to keep the frame visible
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
```

If you want to remain at a certain position you were at before dynamically adding components, you could save the scroll bar value off and then reuse it like so:

```
int myScrollPanesOldPosition = myScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
// dynamically add components
myScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(myScrollPanesOldPosition );
```

Comment: thanks for your response, well i tried to add your code snippet but it's not scrolling to top it going back to bottom again :(

Comment: Hmm, I am pretty sure this works as I've used this method before I think, are you doing this after the components are fully added, on the EDT and validated? Perhaps you need to repaint, I am not sure, I'll look into this later perhaps if I have time.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the code in an SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        myScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
    }
});
```

this will add the code to the end of the Event Dispatch Thread so it should execute AFTER all the components have been validated and painted.

Comment: i tried even this still it is not solving the problem

Comment: @user2318813, works fine for me using JDK7 on Windows 7. Post your `SSCCE`, showing how you tested the code.

Comment: +1 thanks it works :) well i didn't give proper attention in placing the code

Comment: @user2318813, then you should accept the answer to people know the problem has been solved.